# WPF expander style where the header overlaps content

Tags: wpf, header, styles, overlap, expander

I would like a WPF expander control where the header overlaps the main content area.

With the following XAML

```
<Expander Header="Details" ExpandDirection="Left">
    <Grid Background="Blue">
        <TextBlock Text="Details content" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
<ScrollViewer Background="Red" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="Main content"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I end up with:

[image: Img1]
[image]

I want to remove the white area and have the arrow in the top left corner of content area, overlap the red background. maps.bing.com is a similar example of this.

Comment: How bout you show an image of what exactly you want, before and after...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE:

Found one solution that works for me.
Maybe it can be of help to someone else searching for something similar.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Expander_test2.Overlap"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle"
            TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                        StrokeThickness="1.5"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="false"
                                        Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5">
                                    <Path.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                    </Path.LayoutTransform>
                                </Path>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                    Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data"
                                    Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"
                                    TargetName="arrow"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type Expander}"
            TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Canvas>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite"
                                            Margin="1"
                                            MinWidth="0"
                                            MinHeight="0"
                                            Style="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                            FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                                            FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                                            FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite"
                                                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                Focusable="false"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                                    Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible"
                                    TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                                        Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ExpandSite}"
                                        TargetName="HeaderSite" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection"
                                    Value="Left">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                                    Value="Left"
                                    TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                                    Value="Right"
                                    TargetName="HeaderSite"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style"
                                    Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"
                                    TargetName="HeaderSite"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                    Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Expander Canvas.ZIndex="1" Header="Details" ExpandDirection="Left">
            <Grid Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="Details content" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
        <ScrollViewer Background="Red" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Text="Main content"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Note:
Canvas around the ToggleButton
Canvas.ZIndex="1" for Expander
Setter Property="Canvas.Left" in trigger for IsExpanded

Result:

[image]

Comment: I had to do something except make it expand vertically, so this was a helpful starting point. Thanks for sharing.